# Virtuoso SPARQL query length

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I am running a Virtuoso Open Source Server version 07.20.3217.

I am storing triples in there. However, when doing certain SPARQL queries, I get the following error message:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Parentheses are not balanced at '}'
```

I realised that it is not a problem of unbalanced parenthesis, but it is that my query seems to be too long, so that SPARQL just reads a part of it, cutting it in one particular point.

Is it there any option to increase the length of the allowed queries?? Or should I rewrite the query??

I have been looking the documentation, but I have not been able to find it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You have to use HTTP `POST` for queries longer than 1900 bytes, see the documentation [here](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSSparqlProtocol#HTTP%20Request%20Methods)